# Fading image each time I click a button and new image is starting to show on top of first image?

Tags: html, css

I've search ALL day and couldn't find anything.  I'm trying to fade an image to be transparent with another image.  Meaning - when I click a button the transition starts but you have to keep clicking the button to see the 2nd image. Example:  2 of the same images but one is night image and one is a day image.  I want to transition day to night, not by fading the opacity to 0 and then 1, but to have it clicked continuously and you see the transition.

Comment: I'm at a complete loss.  I'm working with the codes provided here.  I want to have 2 buttons - 1 to transition to night and the other to transition back to day.  So I can click either button and it will go to either day or night transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is what you have searched for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var opacityOfNight = 0;
    $('.turnNightBtn').click(function(){

        if (opacityOfNight == 1){
            opacityOfNight = 0;
        } else {
            opacityOfNight += 0.05;

            if(opacityOfNight > 1) {
                opacityOfNight = 1;   
            }   
        }

        $('.night_img').css({
            opacity : opacityOfNight 
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nUBmh/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.  But I forgot to mention, is it possible to have another button that transitions backward?  DAY BUTTON and NIGHT BUTTON.  So if I click the day it will start to transition to day and night button would go to the night transition?

Comment: Oops, one more thing.  I'm trying to stop the turnNightBtn so it doesn't loop back to the day image if I keep clicking it.  The day button works perfect!

Comment: Is it possible to implement this with a thumbnail gallery?

Comment: ofc it is, why it should not :) ... u just applay the opacity thing on each thumbnail and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I put together a basic example that you can use as a basis to get to your goal. I've layered one image over top of the other and then set up a jQuery function to lower the opacity of the top image by 25% per click. You can adjust the class names and values to match your HTML and desired fade amount per click. Hopefully this helps.

```
$(function(){
    var imageOpacity = 1;
    $('button').click(function(){
        if(imageOpacity > 0){
            imageOpacity = imageOpacity - .25;
            $('.image2').css('opacity', imageOpacity);
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/tM9P7/